# Capturing text between square brackets after a substring in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have string like below which is coming from DB.

```
$temp=Array(true);
if($x[211] != 15)
    $temp[] = 211;
if($x[224] != 1)
    $temp[] = 211;
if(sizeof($temp)>1) {
    $temp[0]=false;
}
return $temp;
```

I need to find all the values inside square brackets followed by $x variable. I.e 211 and 224 .

I tried below code which i found in this website as an answer, but it returns all the values in square bracket including the one followed $temp variable.

```
preg_match_all("/\[(.*?)\]/", $text, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Please let me know how can i get this desired results ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting contents of square brackets, avoiding nested brackets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2110617/getting-contents-of-square-brackets-avoiding-nested-brackets)

Comment: What does `"/\$x\[(.*?)\]/"` give you?

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles - I am getting empty array after testing with `` /\$x\[(.*?)\]/ ``

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles - got the solution by using `preg_match_all("^x\[(.*?)\]^",$text,$matches);` . Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

RegEx

```
(?<=\$x\[).*(?=\])
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/kX2bS1/1)

```
$re = "/(?<=\$x\[).*(?=\])/"; 
$str = "Sample String"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

**Explanation**

- `LookBehind` - Matching pattern should come after `$x[` --- `(?<=\$x\[)`. If pattern to be matched is `XYZ` then behind `XYZ` `$X` should exist.
- `.*` match all after the last matching pattern
- `LookAhead` - `(?=\])` - Match all untill `]`

Comment: Could you please explain why this is a good solution to the problem.

Comment: @LIUFA - Added explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Since PHP interpolates variables (variables start with dollar signs) inside double quoted strings, putting the `preg_match_all` regex in a single quoted string prevents that. Although the "$" is still escaped in the regex since it's a regex anchor character.

In this case `/x\[(.*?)\]/` also works, but I think the more precise you can be the better.

```
$text = '
$temp=Array(true);
if($x[211] != 15)
    $temp[] = 211;
if($x[224] != 1)
    $temp[] = 211;
if(sizeof($temp)>1) {
    $temp[0]=false;
}
return $temp;
';

preg_match_all('/\$x\[(.*?)\]/', $text, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => 211 [1] => 224 )
```