# How to get all the characters between [] using Pregmatch php

Tags: php, preg-match

I have a string

```
$str = "[xyz.hlp] into asasa jkljk [xyp.htq] zff [xrt.thg]";
```

I want to get the character from the string and make an array of all those characters . for example for the above string provided I shuould get and array like this

```
$array("xyz.hlp","xyp.htq","xrt.thg");
```

I tried using preg_match(); something like this but it didn't work

```
preg_match('/\[(.*)\]/', $str , $Fdesc);
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Define "won't work." What did you get? You probably want `(.*?)` so it won't be greedy, but always explain how it doesn't work when asking questions.

Comment: The above solution just matches the first one . But I wanted to create an array of every string that is inside the `[ ]`.

Comment: You might find solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24510759/capturing-text-between-square-brackets-after-a-substring-in-php

Comment: @SameerK thanks I should euse `preg_match_all` instead of `preg_match` .

Answer (score 0):

I got the desired output but by using loop and some php string functions

```
<?php
$str = "[xyz.hlp] into asasa jkljk [xyp.htq] zff [xrt.thg]";
$i   = 0;
while ($i != strrpos($str, "]")) {
    $f_pos = strpos($str, "[", $i); // for first position
    $l_pos = strpos($str, "]", $f_pos + 1); // for the last position
    $value = substr($str, $f_pos, ($l_pos - $f_pos) + 1);
    echo $value;
    $i = $l_pos;
}
?>
```